# My app keeps crashing, SQLite database leak error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am currently working on a college project which is a darts calculator app and I keep getting database leak errors even though I think I am closing all the databases and cursors after I use them. I am also getting a "W/IdleConnectionHandler: Removing a connection that never existed!" error at the beginning of the program.

My logcat has these errors:

```
05-01 08:33:47.801 9504-9581/? W/IdleConnectionHandler: Removing a connection that never existed!
05-01 08:43:46.141 9504-9581/? W/IdleConnectionHandler: Removing a connection that never existed!
```

and:

```
05-01 09:08:06.841 4858-4866/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+user+0+com_google_android_gms+databases+auto_complete_suggestions_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
05-01 09:08:06.841 4858-4866/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+user+0+com_google_android_gms+databases+help_responses_db_18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
05-01 09:08:06.841 4858-4866/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+user+0+com_google_android_gms+databases+metrics_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

My database helper class looks like this:

```
package com.dartsapp.niall.darts_calculator_cs2048;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String database_name = "finishes.db";
private static final String table_name = "finishes_table";
//private static final String column1 = "score";
//private static final String column2 = "finish";
private static DatabaseHelper sInstance = null;

public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}


private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, database_name, null, 1);
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.close();
}

public Cursor getData(int playerScore) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select FINISH from "+table_name+" where SCORE = "+ playerScore,null);
    res.close();
    db.close();
    return res;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+table_name+ "(SCORE INTEGER, FINISH INTEGER)");
    String finish2 =
            "INSERT or replace INTO tbl_Contain (SCORE, FINISH) VALUES('2','D1')" ;
    db.execSQL(finish2);

// LONG list of INSERTs - OMITTED

    String finish170 =
            "INSERT or replace INTO tbl_Contain (SCORE, FINISH) VALUES('170', 'T20 T20 BULL')" ;
    db.execSQL(finish170);
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
    onCreate(db);
    db.close();
}

}
```

I am under serious time pressure here so any help would be greatly appreciated!`

Comment: You can't close your Cursor if you mean to return it to the caller. Let the caller close it after consuming it.

Comment: why your executing your query on onCreate

Comment: Because I wanted the data to be put into the database as soon as it is created but I'm inexperienced with android studio so I'm unsure whether this is correct or not. Is there a better way to insert the data?

Comment: You should insert when you need it

Answer (score 0):

you closed the Cursor before getting your records.

you need add this to your code before close Cursor

```
res.moveToFirst(); //move Cursor to first record 
while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {  // while Cursor not point to last record 
Log.v("YOURTAG",  cur.getString("yourString")); // get your data
//ToDo save your data
cur.moveToNext();
}
// ToDo return your data
```

now you can close  Cursor